# SQL inserting data from one table to another gives error "Msg 257"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

The error:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 22
> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed.
> Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Shows up when I try to do the following (in SSMS).
Note: this is not in a stored procedure.

```
/******The original table elements  ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserAccounts] 
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [FullName] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Password] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [IsLoggedIn] bit  NOT NULL,
    [LastLogin] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [LoginCount] int  NOT NULL,
    [VerifyPending] bit  NOT NULL,
    [FilterPreference] int  NOT NULL,
    [LikesCommitted] int  NOT NULL,
    [CommentsCommitted] int  NOT NULL,
    [LoginType] int  NOT NULL,
    [BlogContainerBlogId] int  NOT NULL,
    [ValidationKey] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [ValidationStartTime] datetime  NULL,
    [Validated] bit  NULL
);

/* I then copy the data into a backup table */
select * 
into UserAcctBackup 
from UserAccounts
/* (verified content to be correct) */

/* Added an element to the table (drop, recreate) */
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserAccounts] 
(
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [FullName] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Password] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [IsLoggedIn] bit  NOT NULL,
    [LastLogin] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [LoginCount] int  NOT NULL,
    [VerifyPending] bit  NOT NULL,
    [FilterPreference] int  NOT NULL,
    [LikesCommitted] int  NOT NULL,
    [CommentsCommitted] int  NOT NULL,
    [LoginType] int  NOT NULL,
    [BlogContainerBlogId] int  NOT NULL,
    [ValidationKey] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [ValidationStartTime] datetime  NULL,
    [Validated] bit  NULL,
    [AllowPromotions] bit  NOT NULL       <--- Added this
);

/* Then, attempt to restore the table content from backup */
insert into UserAccounts 
    select * 
    from UserAcctBackup
```

I get this error:

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 22
> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I am only looking to do this as a quick&dirty way of backup/restore one table if/when I make a simple addition of a scalar data item to the table (no FK mucky-muck, etc). I don't understand the reason for this error, nor how to determine which of the two datetime elements *might* be at fault.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Define all your columns in both the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`, and remove the `IDENTITY` property or use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`

Comment: Why, out of interest, are you allowing your users to choose a username that could be up to ~1 Billion characters long?

Comment: Why are you dropping and re-creating the table just to add a column. What's wrong with `alter table`?

Comment: @Dale - :) I just created the db with EF6 defaults, and haven't had a chance to refactor everything yet! :)  trust me, we don't need names that long! LOL!!!

Comment: @Dale - I'll take a look at alter table as an approach!  As you may guess, SQL isn't my 1st language! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added a column to the table, now it has a different structure than the backup table, so you can't just `select *` into it.

You would typically need to enumerate the columns (which is a good practice anyway) to clarify your intent. Also, if the column you added is non-nullable and has no default, then it needs to be given a value.

Eg, for a table with columns `(id, username, fullname, email)` where you would have added a non-nullable `bit` column called `allowPromotions`:

```
insert into UserAccounts (id, username, fullname, email, allowPromotions)
select id, username, fullname, email, 1
from UserAcctBackup
```

If the new column was nullable and we be content with leaving it all `null`, we could get away with:

```
insert into UserAccounts (id, username, fullname, email)
select id, username, fullname, email
from UserAcctBackup
```

Comment: well, what you said makes perfect sense, but when I apply that to the full table/colums layout, like this:

Comment: Like what... @Jim ?

Comment: @GMB - well, what you said makes perfect sense, but I just noticed that it seems the last 2 columns in UserAccounts (Validated and AllowPromotions) are being flagged as "invalid Column Name" - even in the "canned" select top 1000 query (these columns are marked with squiggly underlines).  So, of course, the query you described won't work.  BTW, all columns look ok in Object Explorer; I've never seen this before!

Comment: @Jim In SSMS go to Edit -> Intellisense -> Refresh Local Cache